# Exporting large datasets with python (from json to dataframe to excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently working on a big dataset I've got my hands on after extracting information from 55,488 json files. My problem is I need to export it to an excel file to share it with other users who have no coding experience and depend on this kind of files to visualize and analyze data.

This is how I manage the data:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import numpy as np 

start_time = time.time()
d = {'a':[],'b':[],'c':[],'d':[],'e':[],'f':[],'g':[],'h':[]}
for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\name.of.user\\Documents\\jsons'):
    x = 'C:\\Users\\name.of.user\\Documents\\jsons\\'+files
    with open(x, encoding="Latin-1") as w:
        data = json.load(w)
        for i in range(1,len(data['variables']['arr'])):
            d['a'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['a'])
            d['b'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['b'])
            d['c'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['c'])
            d['d'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['d'])
            d['e'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['e'])
            d['f'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['f'])
            d['g'].append(data['variables']['arr'][i]['g'])
            d['h'].append(data['h'])
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

After executing `print(df.info())` I get this output:

```
RangeIndex: 21829989 entries, 0 to 21829988
Data columns (total 8 columns):
a          object
b          float64
c          object
d          int64
e          int64
f          int64
g          int64
h          object
dtypes: float64(1), int64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 1.3+ GB
```

With a total execution time of 261.85 seconds.

I procede to perform some basic manipulation with this dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index =['a','g','f'],columns='e',values='b',aggfunc=np.sum)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index =['a','g','f'],columns='e',values='d',aggfunc=np.mean)
```

And `print(df1.info())` gives me this output (the same values are true for df2):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 258522 entries, (14650100911701062260, 2018, 7) to (ES9830350285992850013669, 2019, 6)
Data columns (total 31 columns):
1     235167 non-null float64
2     234870 non-null float64
3     234719 non-null float64
4     234233 non-null float64
5     234213 non-null float64
6     233860 non-null float64
7     233617 non-null float64
8     233623 non-null float64
9     233427 non-null float64
10    233495 non-null float64
11    233430 non-null float64
12    233391 non-null float64
13    233265 non-null float64
14    233024 non-null float64
15    233015 non-null float64
16    232933 non-null float64
17    233012 non-null float64
18    232719 non-null float64
19    232858 non-null float64
20    233008 non-null float64
21    232997 non-null float64
22    233109 non-null float64
23    233046 non-null float64
24    233151 non-null float64
25    233347 non-null float64
26    233760 non-null float64
27    233841 non-null float64
28    234016 non-null float64
29    213162 non-null float64
30    213435 non-null float64
31    136948 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(31)
memory usage: 62.3+ MB
```

With a total processing time of 298.68 seconds.

Finally when I try to export both dataframes to a .xlsx file (each dataframe to an independent excel file) with pandas `to_excel()` function, something seems to be wrong as it's been two hours already and not even one excel file has been succesfully created:

```
df1.to_excel('d_a.xlsx')
df2.to_excel('d_b.xlsx')
```

Is there something wrong with this, or the dataframes I'm trying to export? Is there any way to optimize and make this process faster? I appreciate any help and will edit with any extra information should it be requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue with big sized Data.

Here's my solution.

First do a pip install to get the xlsxwriter engine with:

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

then you just add the writer object to the dataframe.to_excel function like this

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

PS.

One easy way for compressing this data is to structure it as a list of lists where the list 0 functions as columns and the rest of them as data.

I've managed to write big xlsx files(500k rows x 30 columns avrg) pretty fast.

It's still json format. (I've seen this kind of structure in webArchive API)

You can create a dataframe like this:

```
 df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([data], columns=[clnm for clnm in data_to_write[0]]) for data in data_to_write[1:]], ignore_index=True)
```

but you need to structure your data like this before the dataframe creation:

```
data = [['column1','column2'],
        ['data_row1','data_row1'],
        ['data_row1','data_row1'],
       ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave the code I've executed running and check tomorrow first thing in the morning for your answer!